# How do I add static data to an excel sql-query?

Tags: sql, excel, union

I have a running query in Excel which gets data from an sql-server. I need to add static data in order to correct old data. I have tried with Union but Excel returns "Incorrect syntax near '.'."

My thought was to use Union:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT "Trying" as column1, "Testing" as coulmn2 FROM table1;
```

But the data "Trying" and "Testing" are not really coming from table1 since I add it myself. Maybe this can't be done?

```
SELECT ft.ArtNr, ft.FaktRadSumma, ft.ordtyp, ft.ForetagKod, ft.FtgNr, 
ft.Period, ft.Redovisnar, fr.FtgNamn, ft.KundKategoriKod, kus.kundklass, 
ft.Date, ft.FaktTB, ft.FaktTG, ar.ArtKod, ar.artprodkonto, xm.arttypbeskr, 
x1kk.kundklassbeskr, ft.faktradkost
FROM IRISJEV01.dbo.ft ft
UNION
SELECT '51143' as ft.ArtNr, 0.001 as ft.FaktRadSumma, 1 as ft.ordtyp, 10 as 
ft.ForetagKod, '100622-02' as ft.FtgNr, 11 as ft.Period, 2018 as 
ft.Redovisnar, 'Stockholm' as fr.FtgNamn, 0 as ft.KundKategoriKod, 'SC' as 
kus.kundklass, '2018-11-07  00:00:00' as ft.Date, 2,24E+06 as ft.FaktTB, 
2,23 as ft.FaktTG, 22 as ar.ArtKod, STD as ar.artprodkonto, 'Klockor & 
timers' as xm.arttypbeskr, 'Syncentral' as x1kk.kundklassbeskr, -2238058 as 
ft.faktradkost
FROM IRISJEV01.dbo.ft ft
```

I expect to get all lines from the part above Union and the one line from below Union with the data specified, e.g. 51143, 0.001, etc...

Excel returns "Incorrect syntax near '.'."

Comment: Remove the aliases (`as ft.ArtNr` et al) they are not required and are not valid  alias names (unless escaped)

Comment: Remove all the aliasing for your union query and it should work fine

Comment: A column alias can't be qualified. E.g. `x1kk.kundklassbeskr` isn't valid. (But `kundklassbeskr` is.)

Comment: You can't reference the columns from the UNION's other select.

Comment: Also, if all the data is static in the `UNION` (second select), then remove the `From IRISJEV01.dbo.ft ft` as well. It's not needed.

Comment: YES! Thanks. I removed the aliases. It works fine. 
Read somewhere that the aliases are needed. Copied from those. 
Thank you so much for the expertise!!